# Suggestion needed to choose dynamic charting platform? Silverlight or SVG?

Tags: jquery, silverlight, charts, svg

We need to build a web app component within which user interacts with 3-5 charts simulated together. I think user will mostly operates some slidebars to control parameters to compute (simulate) and display the charts. So performance of the charts is the key.

We are in the process of selection of platform. And here are what we think

1. Javascript/Jquery seems to be natural choice but it has big memory limitation.
2. Silverlight looks OK since it is running on client and can be written in C#. We can't use some existing mathML though.
3. Last choice might be SVG. Which is, I believe similar to Silverlight in a sense it is xml-based and operates on client. We don't have a good experience with it.

So I would appreciate any suggestion over this selection for dynamic charting. In addition, if you can recommend any library or tool to build such dynamic charting in C# or ASP.NET (MVC), that would be great.

UPDATE: In response to one of commentator below, some constraints are following:

1. Of course, we want to support all browsers if possible but if it takes much time/cost, we would satisfy with IE & FF.
2. It's internet app for possibly subscribed users.
3. We are mainly ASP.NET (MVC) developers with javascript scripting but have some experience with java/php.
4. We expect initial stage of 1000-2000 users.
5. When user move one of sliders, graph with simulated data will be updated.
6. User should see how those charts are changed so importance of graph syncing with data is great.

Comment: Could you elaborate on #1? Just how many data points will you need to plot? I am not sure that the "big memory limitation" is a valid concern with JavaScript-based charts, any more than the other candidates.

Comment: Maybe I didn't put it right. In an example with a jquery chart, jqPlot, when number of points reaches 1000, or something, browser keeps issuing "“A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly. If it continues to run, your compute may become unresponsive.” We don't want that.

Comment: You need to clarify your requirements.  Which browsers do you __need__ to support and which __would__ you like to support?  What is the general purpose of the charts, is it say, an intranet KPI display with limited users?  What are you already familiar with?  How frequently are users expected to visit the charts?  How often does the data behind the charts change?  How important is it that the charts be in sync with the data?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Thanks for comment. They are valuable questions. I will update my question.

Comment: "Satisfied with IE" 9 or do you need support lower versions.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones probably not going with IE9 since it will exclude all XP users if these is any addition issue with IE9.

Comment: 1000-2000 users?  Subscribed to the service in total, or concurrent active users?

Comment: As far as I remember, SilverLight Toolkit line chart takes 4 second to display 2000 points and 9s to display 3000. So this chat is not so good choice for large amount of data. But there is dynamic data display chart for silverlight, it is faster, but not easy for working with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most powerful client-based charting apps are currently:

EXT.JS4 - http://www.sencha.com/

and Highcharts - http://www.highcharts.com/

I know EXT4 is smart enough to render canvas and SVG.

Silverlight and Flash pretty well put you in the same proprietary sinking ship.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am almost sold, especially for sencha ext js4.  Highcharts seems to be slow for our purpose though. Anyway, I will try them out.

Comment: I'm using EXT for the data grid and I am really quite enjoying working with this framework. There's an active community behind it and I think  they're doing a lot of things right. There are numerous videos on the product on youtube as well. My questions in forum posts get answered quickly.